# ¿Como mostrar un collapse desde otro archivo?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, collapse

Tengo la pagina "admin" con un nav bar de 4 enlaces, cada uno de ellos carga una nueva pagina, por ejemplo:
Enlace 1 manda a pagina/admin/enlace1
Enlace 2 manda a pagina/admin/enlace2

Lo que no se como hacer es mostrar la pagina correspondiente a cada enlace, dentro de admin, mediante collapse, es decir que el enlace 1 me despliegue un collapse en admin y que el enlace 2 despliegue otro collapse (ocultando el collapse del enlace 1).

He hecho una practica sencilla con un index y un nav bar de 4 enlaces pero con el código de los collapse dentro del mismo index, no en otra pagina como me gustaría hacer para no saturar de código el index de mi proyecto. Además de que al ir jugando con los enlaces, me va desplegando collapse tras collapse de la siguiente manera:

Dejo el código que me muestra el contenido de cada enlace en un diferente collapse pero si voy presionando todos, no se oculta el anterior y cabe destacar que los elementos que debe mostrar cada collapse estan en el mismo archivo, no en diferente como me gustaria.

¿Alguna pequeña guia de lo que tendria que hacer para acceder a los elementos de cada collapse desde otro archivo y ocultar el collapse anterior para mostrar el seleccionado?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" value="1" onclick="action(this.value)">
    Collapse 1 con button
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" value="2" onclick="action(this.value)">
    Collapse 2 con button
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse3"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" value="3" onclick="action(this.value)">
    Collapse 3 con button
</button>

<div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Parrafo del collapse 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Parrafo del collapse 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse3">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Parrafo del collapse 3
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function action(valor) {
        if (valor == 1) {
            document.getElementById("collapse1").style.display = "visible";
            document.getElementById("collapse2").style.display = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("collapse3").style.display = "hidden";
            alert(valor);


        }
        else if (valor == 2) {
            document.getElementById("collapse2").style.display = "visible";
            document.getElementById("collapse1").style.display = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("collapse3").style.display = "hidden";

            alert(valor);

        }
        else if (valor == 3) {
            document.getElementById("collapse3").style.display = "visible";
            document.getElementById("collapse1").style.display = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("collapse2").style.display = "hidden";

            alert(valor);

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, la verdad es que no entiendo qué es lo que necesitas, trata de resumir mejor lo que tienes y lo que buscas, añade también lo que has intentado. Puedes acompañar con imágenes de referencia o agragr un [example].

Comment: Quiero mostrar diferentes collapse en una pagina, cada uno por medio de un button, pero no quiero que sea visible mas de 1 a la vez. En el script que hice solo me muestra el collapse 1 y de ahi ya no funciona hasta que recargo la pagina otra vez.

Comment: Aunado a esto me gustaría tener el código de cada collapse en diferentes archivos y acceder a ellos desde uno solo, es decir, tener una pagina solo con los botones y al seleccionar un boton, que muestre el collapse que se encuentra en otro archivo.